# Where can I go to find a game graphic artist?

Tags: sprites

Where's a good place to post to find a decent game artist to create a small number of 32-bit sprites? This is for an internal code war framework so it's minimal work - maybe a couple of hours.

Any suggestions where I should post to find someone to do this?

Comment: It would be great if we had a wiki-type answer that addressed not only sprites, but 3-d rendered images, animations, etc. And the separation of paid and unpaid artists is also extremely handy.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer depends on your intention to pay or not to pay for this work, but whatever is the answer you can try on "art & design" forums such as:

- [CGsociety](http://www.cgsociety.org) ( [paid](http://forums.cgsociety.org/forumdisplay.php?f=319) | [unpaid](http://forums.cgsociety.org/forumdisplay.php?f=73) )
- [DeviantArt](http://www.deviantart.com) ( [paid](http://forum.deviantart.com/jobs/offers/) | [unpaid](http://forum.deviantart.com/community/projects/) )
- etc.

or "game creation" forums:

- [indiegamer](http://forums.indiegamer.com) ( [paid](http://forums.indiegamer.com/forumdisplay.php?15-Help-Wanted&s=62b4f7ed342add66929e719ae3b5d6df) )
- [devmaster](http://www.devmaster.net) ( [paid](http://www.devmaster.net/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=43) )
- etc.

Finally you can ask on "pixel art" forums:

- [pixeljoint](http://www.pixeljoint.com) ( [paid & unpaid](http://www.pixeljoint.com/forum/forum_topics.asp?FID=11) )
- [wayofthepixel](http://www.wayofthepixel.net) ( [paid](http://www.wayofthepixel.net/pixelation/index.php?board=6.0) | [unpaid](http://www.wayofthepixel.net/pixelation/index.php?board=14.0) )
- etc.

However, it's indeed harder to find people ready to work for free (not impossible trough) and if you can't afford for this kind of small help you can also consider to make it yourself as ashes999 suggested.

Comment: Of course I will pay - I figured that went without saying. Thank you very much for the suggestions

Comment: +1 for PixelJoint, though you must be keenly aware of forum etiquette there (and wherever you go!) so you receive responses from good artists.

Answer (score 4):

This is a frequent problem that game developers encounter that's hard to surmount. Unless you can get someone on-board full-time for free (like a partner on your development team), I would really recommend learning how to create basic artwork yourself.

With tutorials and basic stuff available on the internet (sprites, textures, icons, etc.) you can quickly learn to create polished *technical* art -- not the most beautiful, but good enough to launch.

I also personally find that Flash is a great tool for creating (vector) art assets. It has a simple but sufficiently diverse toolset to allow you to create good technical art. (Technical means not necessarily creative or polished or stylistic; but technically clean.)

Comment: I don' think that this is great idea. Probably you are the happy one with artistic talents and technicals. But in general i'm sure it is always better to bring skilled artists to your project. But thats only my opinion...

Comment: I'm not artistically talented. But I've found that having a technical foundation and being able to play with shapes, colours, lines, etc. goes a long way.

Comment: I'm a really good programmer. And there are a lot of other things I do well. But I suck at art. Really really suck.

Comment: Me too. Stock photography/textures/icons with some simple animations can go a long, long way. And you don't need to be good at art to do it. That's my opint.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to pay an artist to create custom sprites try:

- http://pixeljoint.com
- http://www.wayofthepixel.net/pixelation/index.php

Alternatively, for internal work that will not be demoed in public you could just use **sprite sheets** that are floating around on the net as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend TIG Source as a nice place to visit. There are many good people in this Indy gaming and gamedev community.

- [Jobs forum (paid contributions)](http://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?board=40.0)
- [Unpaid contributions forum](http://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?board=41.0)

If you go there, please remember to [introduce yourself](http://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?topic=45.0)!

EDIT: if it's XNA related, you could also ask/look at the XNA forums:
[team positions/services wanted/offered](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/42.aspx)