# Where can I find pixel-art artist?

Tags: sprites

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I go to find a game graphic artist?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12846/where-can-i-go-to-find-a-game-graphic-artist)

I'm pretty good programmer, and I want to create new pixel-art-game. I know how to program, visualise and optimize the game. But I can't draw! I think there is a lot of people like me... So.. I'm looking for an artist, who can draw pixel-art sprites.

Where I can find "free" pixel-art artist, who just want to create a game (I think that he should have the similar problem, but instead of looking for artist he looks for programmer).

Comment: I guess this question belongs to careers.stackoverflow.com/, also there already are some duplicates here.

Comment: I found it very tough to find an artist. I really recommend you push yourself and learn art. Good art just has to be stylistically similar, not necessarily high quality.

Comment: I have think about it. And I think that I don't have enough free time to improve my artist skills. I just can make good code, art is not for me now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate of [Where can I go to find a game graphic artist?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/12846/2698)

Answer (score 10):

As Valkea mentioned, the [PixelJoint](http://www.pixeljoint.com/) and [Pixelation](http://www.wayofthepixel.net/) fora are good sources for *finding* pixel artists. You might also try the [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net/) forums.

**However.**

“Unpaid” posts on these sites tend not to be terribly well received. You’ll need to make a very compelling case to convince anyone to work for free, and you’ll get what you pay for. What many developers don’t know is that **pixel art is extremely time- and effort-intensive**, and animations and tilesets are especially taxing.

The good pixel artists will ask for their worth—a relatively high hourly rate times many hours of work. In my experience, making all of the pixel art required for a complete game will take at least as long as the programming. At best, you might find an upcoming artist looking to do something *pro bono* in order to gain exposure.

Programmers seeking artists seem far more common than the reverse. If you are serious, your goal as a developer should be to **make a fun, high-quality game, even if it looks crappy**. With a demo, you can *demonstrate* to artists that you’re not just looking for someone to give you free artwork, and that you have the skills to possibly make it worth their while.

Comment: You are right! I will make demo of game, and demonstrate that to artists...

Answer (score 4):

As I did in [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12846/where-can-i-go-to-find-a-game-graphic-artist/12851#12851) more general question, I would recommend to ask on "pixel art" forums:

- [pixeljoint](http://www.pixeljoint.com) ( [paid & unpaid](http://www.pixeljoint.com/forum/forum_topics.asp?FID=11) )
- [wayofthepixel](http://www.wayofthepixel.net) ( [paid](http://www.wayofthepixel.net/pixelation/index.php?board=6.0) | [unpaid](http://www.wayofthepixel.net/pixelation/index.php?board=14.0) )
- etc. (I don't know any other famous forum dedicated to pixel-art, but there is probably others)

Then you can try on forums dedicated to "game creation":

- [indiegamer](http://forums.indiegamer.com) ( [paid](http://forums.indiegamer.com/forumdisplay.php?15-Help-Wanted&s=62b4f7ed342add66929e719ae3b5d6df) )
- [devmaster](http://www.devmaster.net) ( [paid](http://www.devmaster.net/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=43) )
- etc.

And finally on "art & design forums"...

Comment: Thank you! It's good solution. Around me only programmers, and I forgot, that there is artist forums too ;)

Comment: I would also have a look around the Tigsource Forums, those guys love their pixel art :)